# How to load assembly [Systems.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection] into Powershell

Tags: powershell, .net-assembly, stringcollection

I semi understand what I'm asking and have tried to research this as best as I'm able.

I'm trying to use an object of type [Systems.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection]:

```
$newDBFiles = new-object Systems.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection;
```

I get the error:

```
new-object : Cannot find type [Systems.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:15
+ $newDBFiles = new-object Systems.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection;
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I've tried loading the assembly a few different ways without success:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Collections.Specialized") | Out-Null;
    add-type -AssemblyName systems;
    add-type -AssemblyName systems.collections;
```

The documentation says that `Add-Type` will accept a location to the .dll.  Looking at the documentation for the [StringCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)) the .dll I want is `System.dll`.  That sounds like it should already be present on my system.

When I look at the assemblies already loaded, I see this one, which appears to me be correct:

```
[appdomain]::currentdomain.getassemblies() | sort -property fullname | format-table fullname

System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

There's numerous posts about using the type but I couldn't find any on how to load the specific assembly.  Do I need a special .dll file?

Comment: `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection`

Comment: Argh.  Thank you very much.  Sorry to waste any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the comment from @PetSerAl: You have an **s** after `System` that shouldn't be there. Do this instead

```
$newDBFiles = new-object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection;
```